# Django Form 'int' object has no attribute 'required' for field that is added in function

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

In Django 1.6 and crispy forms, I am trying to add `forum_id_number` which is returned from a API call after the user submits. However, I am getting a

```
Exception Value:    
'int' object has no attribute 'required'
```

after I submit the form. I have verified `self.fields['forum_id_number'] = response["User"]["Id"]` is causing this.

---

```
class AccountForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AccountForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-lg-2 control-label'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-lg-4'

        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Fieldset('Account Modify',
                'irc_name',
                'forum_username',
                Hidden('user_assigned', '{{ user.pk }}'),
                Hidden('forum_id_number', '0'),
                ),

            FormActions(
                Submit('submit', 'Submit', css_class='btn-primary')
                )
         )

    def clean_forum_username(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['forum_username']
        SLUG = "users/" + data + ".json"
        status_code, response = do_request(SLUG)
        if status_code != 200:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Your username was not"
                                        " found! Please check the"
                                        " the spelling. Also, your"
                                        " forum username is your"
                                        " forum sign in name.")
        elif status_code == 200:
            self.fields['forum_id_number'] = response["User"]["Id"]
        return data
```

---

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    user_assigned = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
            related_name='r_assigned')
    irc_name = models.CharField(max_length="25",
            unique=True)
    forum_id_number = models.BigIntegerField(unique=True)
    forum_username = models.CharField(max_length="50",
            unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.irc_name
```

Answer (score 1):

`self.fields['forum_id_number']` is an instance of a `forms.Field` subclass. It describes the attribute `self.forum_id_number`. The line `self.fields['forum_id_number'] = response["User"]["Id"]` overwrites this field description and sets it to an instance of an `(Big?)Integer` object. This instance of course has no attribute `required`.

The 'correct' way to set a value for `forum_id_number` is to use `self.forum_id_number = response["User"]["Id"]` or `self.cleaned_data['forum_id_number'] = response["User"]["Id"]`.

Correct is in quotation marks because in this case it really isn't the correct way. There is no way of knowing if the field `forum_id_number` is cleaned in any `clean_FIELD` method, so you don't know if you should set `self.forum_id_number` or `self.cleaned_data['forum_id_number']`. Now in the case of `forum_id_number`, there is no security issue, but anyone with Firebug or something similar can change the value of `user_assigned`. It is generally better to exclude hidden fields from the form, and set the values on the instance itself in the `save` method of the form. Of course you can't raise a `ValidationError` in the `save` method (well, you can, but it'd produce a `500 Internal Server Error`), so you'll have to get the user id in your `clean_forum_username` method:

```
class AccountForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ....
    def clean_forum_username(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['forum_username']
        SLUG = "users/" + data + ".json"
        status_code, response = do_request(SLUG)
        if status_code != 200:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Your username was not"
                                        " found! Please check the"
                                        " the spelling. Also, your"
                                        " forum username is your"
                                        " forum sign in name.")
        elif status_code == 200:
            self.response = response
        return data

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # self.response should be valid, otherwise a `ValidationError` would've been raised
        self.instance.forum_id_number = self.response['User']['Id']
        return super(AccountForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```